# Postgres, meteor and fibers? Argggh not friends?

Tags: postgresql, meteor, coffeescript

I'm trying to use postgres with Meteor using Coffeescript. Unfortunately since two days with no success. There is so much confusion in my head right now..

I'm having the error `Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber.` exactly where I do the Meteor.WrapAsync inside runQuery().

I'm using the npm module `'pg'` with `npmRequire`.
So my service code is like this:

```
dropTables: =>
        identifier= 'Drop tables'
        Meteor.wrapAsync(runQuery) "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + mapping + " ;" , identifier
        console.log 'Finished running query'

runQuery = (theQuery, identifier) =>
        pg = Meteor.npmRequire 'pg'

        console.log 'About to connect to postgres for ', identifier
        pg.connect conString, (err, client, done) ->
            _logServices.Info 'About to query for ', identifier

            myResult = Meteor.wrapAsync((callback) ->
                client.query theQuery , (err, result) ->
                    if err
                        _logServices.Error 'Error while '+ identifier +' with the query: ', theQuery
                    else
                        _logServices.Info "Success " + identifier
                        _logServices.Info 'closing connection for ', identifier
                callback(null, 1)
            )()
        done()
        pg.end()
        console.log "still here!"
```

What I'm exactly trying to achive is to run the postgres things asyncronusly. In order to do one thing per time, but probably I'm missusing the fibers.

Comment: What is your question? Whether Postgres, Meteor and Fibers are friends :) ? I wouldn't know, maybe have a look at their Facebook pages?

Comment: Sorry, just kidding. But you don't actually ask what we can do for you. Which of the logged errors did you see? And what was their full message?

Comment: @JosHarink Ahahahah thanks for the hint! I've just edited the question :)

Comment: In my current project with Postgres, I use the numtel:pg package. If you don't need reactivity, you also look at package postgresql: https://github.com/austinrivas/meteor-postgresql. Or use their source code to investigate. I think what you need is Meteor.bindEnvironment instead of Meteor.wrapAsync.

Comment: And a quick check: if you comment out all your `_logServices.*` lines, so you only have 'npm' code running? Does that work?